# How to use "Export As" option for SVG conversion in Illustrator Script

Tags: javascript, svg, jsx, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am trying to write a script for illustrator that will export my Ai into SVG. But my problem is when i use the `exportFile()` function its just export the files like how a ***File > Save as > SVG*** option would save the file. But what I am really trying to figure out is how I can use the ***File > Export > Export as > SVG*** to save my files.

I am using this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9AZ2nvhaNNDjxLeQSeoeJDKav2otsHw/view?usp=sharing) as my test file, and using ***Save as*** option gives me around *1.5MB* of file size and ***Export as*** gives me around 800KB. I need this exact SVG options when converting the file[image]

and this is the code I am using right now

```
var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsSVG();

exportOptions.cssProperties = SVGCSSPropertyLocation.STYLEATTRIBUTES;
exportOptions.optimizeForSVGViewer = true;
exportOptions.embedRasterImages = true;

app.activeDocument.exportFile(File("~"), ExportType.SVG, exportOptions);
```

Can anyone please help me with how I can get this done? Or any other useful ways or tips would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert in SVG. As far as I can tell, the full list of the options (about 19 items) you can get here: https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/ExportOptionsSVG.html And it's not unlikely that the options you can use from script API and options you can use from UI are intersected but not equal sets. Illustrator's developers love to make you to keep your brain in a good shape, you know.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment I was really hoping to see your thoughts on this as you have answered one of my previous question.

Comment: As for the size (1,5 MB vs 800 KB), the difference looks like a result of either 'Minify' option in UI or `ExportOptionsSVG.compressed` preference in API. I don't know if they're the same things in both cases? The word 'compression' looks more like a ZIP/LZW compression not a 'minification' (which is the way to reduce size of the code _without compression_), but who knows — Illustrator's developers are quite creative guys. You can try to turn on/off this property and see. (Btw, you have two identical lines in your code `exportOptions.embedRasterImages = true;`, it doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: Hey Yuri, Thanks again. I have tried all the options that are offered by `ExportOptionsSVG()` But none of them reduce the file size as the Export option does. And thank you for identifying the fault on the code. I will change it. But I have tried more or less all the options but it does not works as I want it to. I have also tried a different method to accomplish my goal but that way also creates new challenges. Do you think I can dm you about this in some way that you prefer.? Let me know. I would love that if you can help me on this at any or your convenient time. Thanks

Comment: I just added the tag `svg`. Let's hope someone with better knowledge of SVG takes look on it.

Comment: The only solution I can think (a very clumsy one) to perform a number of text changes (find/change with RegExp) directly within the exported SVG file. It's a plain text file after all, you can edit it as much as you like. But it would be extremely suboptimal solution. For desperate cases only. And you should have the quite deep knowledge about how SVG format is wired inside.